# Connection refused when connecting to server from ESP8266

Tags: api, http, server, iot, nodemcu

I have a server on localhost. I am trying to send http request to the server from ESP8266 but connection is not being established. This is the server URL that I am trying to access:

`const char* serverUrl = "http://localhost:3000/verifyRFID";`

Wifi connection to ESP8266 is successful. There are no issues there.

```
 http.begin(wifiClient, serverUrl);
 http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);
 Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
 Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
```

Http response code is -1 which means connection is refused. The APIs are running on Postman and same htpp requests are running on frontend.

Comment: @Juraj How do I call localhost on ESP8266? I am using ESP8266

Comment: 'localhost' is the device itself. on your esp8266 it is your esp8266. to connect to the computer use the IP address of the computer

Comment: I changed the serverUrl to "http://192.168.0.104:3000/getTempReceipt"; but its still not working

Comment: is the port 3000 open on Firewall on the computer?

Comment: Ohh yes the port was closed. Thank you so much!